# Null reference exception- Takephotoasync xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the media plugin by James Montemagno. I have installed the plugin and added all the required permissions. However, when I run my app, I get a null reference exception on the first line of the following code:

`image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>{var stream = file.GetStream();file.Dispose();return stream;});`

I tried looking for a solution for almost 2 full days with no luck! 
Any help would be most appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you put breakpoints in? Can you determine whether `image` is null or `file`?

Comment: Can you show us more code? It's hard to know what's going on from a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to [download the source](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

[HERE](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/samples/MediaSample/MediaSample/MediaPage.xaml.cs) you can find a sample how to use the plugin.

```
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
      PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
      Directory = "Sample",
      Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
      return;

    DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
      var stream = file.GetStream();
      file.Dispose();
      return stream;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because ImageSource.FromStream releases always the stream created ... Here is my code which takes pictures and display the pictures in a binded ListView.

In short, I get the original stream from the plugin then I convert it into byte[] and store it in a dedicated object.  When I need to display the picture into an image source, I create a new stream from the byte[] and use it with the ImageSource.FromStream method from Xamarin.Forms.

```
    public class PictureModel
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        public ImageSource ImageSource => ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(File));
    }

    public class PicturesViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PictureModel> Pictures { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PictureModel>();

        public ICommand TakePictureCommand => new Command(async () =>
        {
            var stream = await TakePictureAsync();
            var picture = new PictureModel { File = await ImageConverter.ReadFully(stream) }; // custom method to convert stream into byte[]
            Pictures.Add(picture);
        });

        protected async Task<Stream> TakePictureAsync()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = false,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
            });

            if (file == null)
                return null;

            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

> Maybe I need to dispose the local stream in the TakePictureCommand but
>   I didn't test yet.

And the XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="200">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="200" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Here is the problem from Xamarin  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18994/imagesource-fromstream-dispose